# Gorm query without gorm.Model columns

Tags: go, go-gorm

How can I omit the columns that come from the gorm.Model. E.g. CreatedDate, modifiedDate.

Consider the following model:

```
type User struct{
    gorm.Model
    Firstname string
    Lastname string
}
```

Now I can select specific column with:

```
db.Select("Firstname").Find(&users)
```

However, while it excludes the Lastname column, it does not exclude the columns that come from the gorm.Model. So the result would look something like:

```
[{"ID":0,"CreatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","UpdatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","DeletedAt":null,"Firstname":"Foobar"}]
```

I want only the Firstname column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your `User` type without including `gorm.Model` struct

```
type User struct{
    Firstname string
    Lastname string
}
```

Alternatively, you can use two types, one with `gorm.Model` and the second without it. You can use the latter when retrieving values without `gorm.Model` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I make a second User struct (which is not that clean in my opinion) It must have a different name. I assume I have to tell gorm to look on the User table even though the model has a different name, correct?

Comment: Of course, if you define a second type struct, it will have a different name. You will use the second type struct only as `Find` parameters