# How to add autoincrement to a table

Tags: go, auto-increment, go-gorm

I am trying to add autoincrement to my table in a Go project but it doesn't seem to be working for me

```
`gorm:"primary_key;column:uuid;not_null;type:int(32);autoIncrement" json:"uuid"`
```

keeping this in the struct of the given field. (Also tried AUTO_INCREMENT, autoincrement but not working)

Comment: afaik if you "inherit" from gorm base model, it will add this identity column for you. See this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949645/gorm-query-without-gorm-model-columns

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation of the model field tags](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags), it says (emphasis mine):

type: column data type, prefer to use compatible general type, e.g: bool, int, uint, float, string, time, bytes, which works for all databases, and can be used with other tags together, like not null, size, autoIncrement… *specified database data type like varbinary(8) also supported, when using specified database data type, it needs to be a full database data type, for example: MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT*

That means that if you use a specific datatype like `int(32)` as you have done, you need to specify the full type string:

```golang
`gorm:"primary_key;column:uuid;type:int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"uuid"`
```

Comment: oh got it seems to work for me now. Thanks